# Github pages not showing up, getting a string instead

Tags: markdown, github-pages

For my github pages website, i've tried to use the markdown tables, but they aren't working:

```
| hello | hi |
| --- | --- |
| hi | hello |
```

I get the string like this:

```
| hello | hi | | --- | --- | | hi | hello |
```

You can see it from [this](https://github.pato05mc.tk/PatoBot/methods/removeAdmin.html) page

Comment: Follow this guide: https://nicolas-van.github.io/easy-markdown-to-github-pages/

Comment: @Renan Souza I can't find anything useful in that post...

Comment: you need to add `<br>` instead of new lines

Comment: by the way take a look at <table> instead

Comment: Try removing the first and last '|' character on each line (as described here: https://guides.github.com/pdfs/markdown-cheatsheet-online.pdf)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl i know HTML tags, but here I need to use markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table must be surrounded by blank lines:

```
Usage: <code>$PatoBot->removeAdmin($id);</code>

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| $id | The user id to be removed from the admin list |

Returns true if the user was in the admin array and was removed, false if not.
```

Notice that I removed the `<br>` tags and added a blank line before and after the table.

The reason why this is required for GitHub Pages, but not GitHub itself is that a different Markdown processor is used. While the two implementations are very similar there are a few differences, this being one of them.

Jekyll (the static site generator used by GitHub Pages) does include [support for Commonmark](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#commonmark), however, according to the [readme in the repo](https://github.com/github/jekyll-commonmark-ghpages#jekyll-commonmark-ghpages), the GitHub Markdown variant is only in testing at this time. The docs also seem to suggest that extensions (including tables) are not enabled by default, so if you use it, you would need to also explicitly enable the extensions you want. According to the [most recent information](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0/) provided by GitHub, GitHub Pages uses Jekyll's default, [Kramdown](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/#kramdown), which supports tables by default, but is more strict about requiring tables to be surrounded by blank lines than Commonmark with the tables extension. For that matter, I'm not sure Commonmark is even available in Pages. Jekyll added support in version 3.1, and Pages [currently supports](https://github.blog/2016-11-02-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3/) version 3.3, but nowhere has GitHub stated that they support Commonmark on GitHub pages since their February 2016 announcement that they only support Kramdown (at least I couldn't find it anywhere).

Given the above, the Markdown used for GitHub Pages, needs to conform to [Kramdown's rules](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/documentation.html).